# ExtJS 6 Build-in classes to work with SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, extjs, extjs6

I want to parse SVG document structure, handle events and change attributes. For example, I have a map splited into `<g>` groups. I want to handle mouseouver,  mouseout, click events on a group and change attributes like fill and stroke.

I can do it with JS, but I want to know is there special functional in ExtJS 6 to work with SVG out of the box? I cant find good examples in the Internet.

As I understand [Ext.draw.engine.Svg](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.draw.engine.Svg.html) is used to generate and edit SVG. To handle events and change attributes I can use generic [Ext.dom.Element](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html). Am I right?